# Does all the programming languages have assemblers

Tags: c++, assembly

I've found that Go language have its assembler, various compilers of C language have their own assemblers like Turbo C, LCC, OpemWatcom. But some are only asemblers like nasm, gas, etc. Why the compilers of high level languages comes with an assembler, if the compiler has to convert the source code into assembly code, then all the programming languages must be having their own assemblers. Please someone explain me this.

Comment: Not all programming languages are the same?

Comment: No, __all programming languages__ implies languages that are not compiled (i.e scripting languages are interpreted not compiled), they won't be using assemblers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does all the programming languages have assemblers

No.

Modern C++ compiler can output machine code (or intermediate object code in case of llvm) directly, without the need to generate assembly. The assembler is optional and if exists, it is provided as a convenient tool for the programmer for code inspection.

Comment: ...and languages like Java which don´t produce "real" programs (but files  meant to be processed by another software each time the program is started) have no assembler too because they don´t need one for their file format.

Answer (score 1):

Can only one driver drive a particular car?  No.  The car is the assembler and can be made for multiple drivers.

It is in the best interest of the company that invents a processor to both document the instruction set machine code as well as an assembly language.  Assembly language is not a universal thing, it is very specific to each assembler, the program that parses it and turns it into machine code.  So the processor vendors documentation should use some assembly language to make the documentation readable.  It is in their best interest to promote the new processor to create or hire someone to create an assembler and other tools, but you always have to create an assembler, if for no other reason than to validate the processor.   So a generic assembler will exist.

Then compiler vendors may choose of course to support a generic one, a competitors, or make their own or any combination.  And reasons for those choices can be many.  For various reasons some compilers may choose to not generate assembly language as an intermediate step but go straight to machine code.

Your typical generic retargettable compiler will tend to support the compiler-assembler-linker model.  The might do more than that but will tend for that model.  Again which assembler, which linker?  Many reasons why they might make their own or support a generic one.  but if they use that model they have to at least pick one to support.  Someone in the business of selling that compiler will likely want to control not just the compiler but all of the toolchain including a gui.  They make take from open source or do their own but it is in their best interest to control their destiny.